# Regex output has empty strings i cannot understand

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, string

I am kind of new with regular expressions and I am getting some empty strings in my output list that I cannot understand. I have the following string:

```
string ='[-1, <samp>clear</samp>, -1, None, -1] [-1, None, -1, None, -1, <time class="text-nowrap" datetime="2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z" id="availability-time"></time>, -1, None, -1'
```

I am trying to extract the word between the `<samp> tags (which is "clear")` and the date which is `2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z`. Although my patterns seem to be working well, when I combine them together with a logical operator or (|), empty strings appear in the output list.

***Example:***

```
import re

pattern = '\>([a-zA-Z]+)\<'
pattern2= '(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z][\d:\.[a-zA-Z]+)'

string = '[-1, <samp>clear</samp>, -1, None, -1] [-1, None, -1, None, -1, <time class="text-nowrap" datetime="2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z" id="availability-time"></time>, -1, None, -1'

print(re.findall(pattern,string))
print(re.findall(pattern2,string))
```

**Output**

```
['clear']
['2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z']
```

Now when I combine `pattern` with `pattern2` with `|` I get the following result:

```
import re
pattern = '\>([a-zA-Z]+)\<|(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z][\d:\.[a-zA-Z]+)'

string = '[-1, <samp>clear</samp>, -1, None, -1] [-1, None, -1, None, -1, <time class="text-nowrap" datetime="2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z" id="availability-time"></time>, -1, None, -1'

print(re.findall(pattern,string))
```

**Output**

```
[('clear', ''), ('', '2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z')]
```

Where do these empty strings come from? Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your observed output is just the expected behavior of `re.findall` when you have defined a capture group.  In this case, the first entry in each tuple is the first capture group (from the `<samp>` portion of the pattern), while the second entry is the second capture group (from the timestamp).  Your alternation will only match one of these two capture groups, so the output will always be 2-tuples with one empty string.

One possible workaround here would be to completely avoid capture groups:

```
pattern = '(?<=>)[a-zA-Z]+(?=<)|\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}[a-zA-Z][\d:\.[a-zA-Z]+'
string = '[-1, <samp>clear</samp>, -1, None, -1] [-1, None, -1, None, -1, <time class="text-nowrap" datetime="2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z" id="availability-time"></time>, -1, None, -1'
print(re.findall(pattern,string))  # ['clear', '2021-03-22T17:06:03.000Z']
```

By making a slight change in the `<samp>` portion of the pattern to use lookarounds, we can avoid capture groups.  Then, each match from `re.findall` will be a single entry in a list.